# How can I transform a \defverbatim environment in a \newcommand?

Tags: beamer, macros, verbatim

I have in my `beamer` presentation a lot of `\defverbatim` like this one

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{manni}

\newminted{SQL}{fontsize=\scriptsize, 
linenos=false,
numbersep=10pt,
gobble=0,
frame=none,
framesep=5mm} 

\begin{document}

\defverbatim[colored]\interfaceTime{
    \begin{SQLcode}
    interface Time: Object {
    ...
    unsigned short   hour();
    boolean          is_equal(in Time other_date);
    Interval         subtract_time(in Time other_time);
    };

\end{SQLcode}
}

\newcommand{\Code}[2]{\verbatim{\begin{#2} #1 \end{#2}}}

    \begin{frame}
        \interfaceTime
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \Code{CREATE TABLE EMP;}{SQLcode}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to create a custom `\newcommand` with some parameters to avoid create a lot of `\defverbatim`.
This is the message that I got

```
(no line number):
Runaway argument?
{\begin {SQLcode} CREATE TABLE EMP; \end {SQLcode}} \end {beamer@fram\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xverbatim.
<inserted text> 
    \par 
<*> main.tex
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: you can not use verbatim in the argument of another command. (the syntax you suggest for `\newcommand` would be incorrect even without verbatim, you have not given the command name you are defining)

Comment: What is the advantage of your desired `\Code{CREATE TABLE EMP;}{SQLcode}` and not simply using `\begin{SQLcode}
     CREATE TABLE EMP;
     \end{SQLcode}`?

Comment: @samcarter your solution don't work in my beamer presentation. I would like the `\newcommand` to be possible use the same idea over my frames.

Comment: @B.Monteiro It works in frames with the `[fragile]` option.

Comment: @samcarter Sorry, I forgot to inform. I need the frame not to be `[fragile]` because I'm goint to mix some text + code

Comment: @B.Monteiro Fragile frames can have text and code

Answer (score 1):

No need to make things more complicate than necessary, I would simply use `\begin{SQLcode} ... \end{SQLcode}` directly without wrapping it in additional layers of commands.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted{SQL}{fontsize=\scriptsize, 
linenos=false,
numbersep=10pt,
gobble=0,
frame=none,
framesep=5mm} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
text

\begin{SQLcode} 
CREATE TABLE EMP; 
\end{SQLcode}

text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```